# How to filter rows by values of one column?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I need to get several columns form sql query. Then I have to filter this answer by the "distinct" values of one column, but in the output I need to have all columns, not only this which values has to be distinct. Can anybody help me? Order by clause is not an answer for me.

```
A,B,C,D
E,F,G,H
I,J,C,L
M,N,Z,H
```

Above is a simple rows output. Please have a look onto 3rd column. Let's assume that we don't know how many rows do we have. I need to select only rows which has distinct value in 3rd column. (C,G,Z) - We need to filter anyone from "C" rows.

Comment: Can you post your query and/or the table definition?

Comment: Given you example, row 1 and 3 have the value C in the 3rd. column.  Which row (1 or 3) did you hope to have in your final result, and why?

Comment: I don't care which of these rows I need. Any one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've arbitrarily chosen to use col1 to break ties on col3. You can adjust the `order by` portion of the `partition` to suit your needs.

```
/* Set up test data */
declare @test table (
    col1 char(1),
    col2 char(1),
    col3 char(1),
    col4 char(1)
)

insert into @test
    (col1, col2, col3, col4)
    select 'A','B','C','D' union all
    select 'E','F','G','H' union all
    select 'I','J','C','L' union all
    select 'M','N','Z','H' 

/* Here's the query */
;with cteRowNumber as (
    select col1, col2, col3, col4, 
           row_number() over (partition by col3 order by col1) as RowNumber
        from @test
)
select col1, col2, col3, col4
    from cteRowNumber
    where RowNumber = 1
```

Returns

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
----------------------------
A       B       C       D
E       F       G       H
M       N       Z       H
```

Answer (score 0):

[`ROLL UP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189305%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) or [`CUBE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175939%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) could be helpful for your problem, since they can aggregate (i.e. subtotal) data based on the `GROUP BY` and still return the individual rows.